# How to return appropriate value in a multiple choice selection for form?

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, contact-form

I am building a feedback page that asks the user to select how they felt about their training. They can rate the service as "Excellent", "Good", or "Poor." I have seen some similar questions that only address if something was checked, an in that case it was said to declare a explicit value. which I guess could work for a "yes" response. But what about when you have multiple options?

Not sure where my VB Script is wrong.

**mailers/training_feedback_send.asp**

```
<html>
<head>
<%
Sub ProcessContact
  Response.Buffer = true    
  dim gRating, gTrainerKnowledgeable, gNotKnowl, gTrainingExperience, gTrainingMaterials, gRateUI, gTs150Perform, gTs150NonPerformReason, gRestorationsAttempted, gRestorationsSuccessful, gRestorationsUnsuccessful, gFeatureChange, gFutureUpdates, gPurchasingMotivation, gAdditionalQuestions, gContactRequest, gFullName, gEmail

  gRating = Request.Form("Rating")
  gTrainerKnowledgeable = Request.Form("TrainerKnowledgeable")
  gNotKnowl = Request.Form("gNotKnowl")
  gTrainingExperience = Request.Form("TrainingExperience")
  gTrainingMaterials = Request.Form("TrainingMaterials")    
  gRateUI = Request.Form("RateUI")
  gTs150Perform = Request.Form("Ts150Perform")
  gTs150NonPerformReason = Request.Form("Ts150Perform")
  gRestorationsAttempted = Request.Form("RestorationsAttempted")
  gRestorationsSuccessful = Request.Form("RestorationsSuccessful")
  gRestorationsUnsuccessful = Request.Form("RestorationsUnsuccessful")  
  gFeatureChange = Request.Form("FeatureChange")
  gFutureUpdates = Request.Form("FutureUpdates")
  gPurchasingMotivation = Request.Form("PurchasingMotivation")
  gAdditionalQuestions = Request.Form("AdditionalQuestions")
  gContactRequest = Request.Form("ContactRequest")

  gFullName = Request.Form("FullName")
  gEmailAddress = Request.Form("EmailAddress")


  msg = msg & "How would you rate the overall effectiveness of the on-site training?: " & gRating & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Did you feel that the trainer was knowledgeable on the product and answered your questions to your satisfaction? If not, explain why: " & gTrainerKnowledgeable & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Did you feel that the trainer was knowledgeable on the product and answered your questions to your satisfaction? If not, explain why: " & gNotKnowl & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "How would you rate your training experience on a scale of 1 - 5, where 1 is poor and 5 is excellent?: " & gTrainingExperience & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Do you find the published training materials helpful?(quickstart guide, tutorials, etc.): " & gTrainingMaterials & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "How would you rate the user interface (GUI) in terms of ease of use and clarity of information?: " & gRateUI& chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Does the TS-150 perform as you anticipated? " & gTs150Perform & chr(10)& chr(13) 

  msg = msg & "If not, in what way is the performance different?: " & gTs150NonPerformReason & chr(10)& chr(13) 

  msg = msg & "How many restorations have you attempted?: " & gRestorationsAttempted & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "How many were successful?: " & gRestorationsSuccessful & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Please describe the problems on any unsuccessful restorations. For example, did they fail to mill? Did they not seat well? Were there problems with the material?: " & gRestorationsUnsuccessful & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Are there any features of the TS150 that you would change? If so what would they be?: " & gFeatureChange & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "What features would you like to see in future updates to the design software and mill software?: " & gFutureUpdates & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "What was your primary motivation for purchasing IOS products?: " & gPurchasingMotivation & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Do you have additional questions or would you like additional training?: " & gAdditionalQuestions & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Would you like to be contacted as a follow-up to this survey?: " & gContactRequest & chr(10)& chr(13)

  msg = msg & "Full Name: " & gFullName & chr(10)& chr(13)
  msg = msg & "Email Address: " & gEmailAddress & chr(10)& chr(13)
```

**pages/training-feedback.aspx**

```
<form action="/mailers/training_feedback_send.asp" method="post" name="Form1" id="trainingFeedback">
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Training and Product Feedback</legend>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="twelve columns">
            <label>How would you rate the overall effectiveness of the on-site training?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="Excellent">Excellent<br>
            <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="Good">Good<br>
            <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="Poor">Poor<br>
          </div>

          <div class="twelve columns">
            <label>Did you feel that the trainer was knowledgeable on the product and answered your questions to your satisfaction? 
            <br>If not, explain why.</label>
            <input type="radio" name="TrainerKnowledgeable" value="yes"><span>Yes</span>
            <input type="radio" name="TrainerKnowledgeable" value="no"><span>No</span>
            <textarea id="gNotKnowl" name="gNotKnowl" class="twoLines" rows="2" placeholder="reason"></textarea>
          </div>
```

Comment: As a side-note: if you provide your users with 3 choices ranging from good to bad I'd recommend making the middle one sound more neutral, e.g. Excellent/Fair/Poor. A selection Excellent/Good/Poor is biased.

Comment: 1. The yes/no question should be radio buttons too, not checkboxes (you can't answer both Yes and No at the same time). 2. The form handling script is requesting a field named "TrainerKnowledgeable", but there is no such field on the form -- the checkboxes are called "checkbox1" and "checkbox2".

Comment: @Martha A yes/no question is typically implemented via a single checkbox, because its 2 states (checked/unchecked) indicate either yes or no. Using radio buttons would just require more GUI space without providing additional benefits.

Comment: @Ansgar, look at the OP's code. He's got a Yes checkbox and a No checkbox. That's incorrect no matter how you look at it. (Also, it can be much more user-friendly to have Yes/No radio buttons, because with a checkbox, it's not always totally intuitive that checked=yes and unchecked=no.)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ok good catch on the checkbox needing to be a radio button. I implemented that and updated the code. Unfortunately for this project I do not have access to the server logs yet. The form that I have in production I ask the user to manually type in "Y" or "N".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was multiple problems with my original question. Because there were multiple choice options where only one selection may be made at a time, it was necessary to change `<input type="checkbox"` to `<input type="radio"`. It was necessary to declare a value, and I gave each option an `id` (though may not be necessary). Here is what passed successfully

**pages/training-feedback.aspx**

```
<input type="radio" name="Rating" id="RatingE" value="Excellent">Excellent<br>
<input type="radio" name="Rating" id="RatingG" value="Good">Good<br>
<input type="radio" name="Rating" id="RatingP" value="Poor">Poor<br>
```

In my `.asp` file I added the following

**mailers/training_feedback_send.asp**

```
dim gRating

gRating = Request.Form("Rating")

msg = msg & "How would you rate the overall effectiveness of the on-site training?: " & gRating & chr(10)& chr(13)
```

Here is what I got in my email

[image]

---

The above should address anyone attempting something similar. It should be noted however that regarding the "server error" that I was getting. It was because of how I declared the variable for the receiving email in my `.asp` file. After hard coding the variable, there was no issue.

```
objCDO.From = "email@example.com"
```

And that is what shows up now in the "from" field. You can set up your own email according to your need. But I would suggest a decriptive name like `feedback@yoursite.com`

Above my hard coded email, I added the following

```
msg = msg & "Email Address: " & gEmailAddress & chr(10)& chr(13)
```

because of the fact that my form collected an email from the visitor of the site. And likewise, you might want to do that. I previously made the mistake of having

```
objCDO.From = gEmailAddress
```

Which caused an error if that field was blank. That may not be an issue if you have form validation. But in our case, the project manager wanted all of the fields to be completely optional.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `<input type="checkbox">`, use the [Radio Button](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/input.html) input type:

```
<input type="radio" name="Rating" value="Excellent" checked>Excellent<br>
<input type="radio" name="Rating" value="Good">Good<br>
<input type="radio" name="Rating" value="Poor">Poor<br>
```

**Edit**: I added the `checked` attribute. From the above link:

> Some browsers require one radio button in a group to be selected at
>   all times. To ensure that an appropriate default choice is made,
>   authors may wish to define one of the radio **INPUT** elements as
>   **CHECKED.**

Comment: Thank you, I implemented this. And tried to adjust the VBScript but seem to still be missing something in that part

Comment: Hmmm, see the topic **Radio Buttons** at [Html Forms](http://w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) at W3Schools. Are you seeing the radio buttons in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing the radio buttons. I meant not that I am missing those elements but that I am still getting an error when I click submit. thanks, I am researching VBScript at the moment as well.

Comment: @JGallardo You didn't mention anything about getting an error before. Please update your question with the exact error code and message as well as the line raising the error.

Comment: @JGallardo The answer was provided by DavidRR, not me.

Comment: @DavidRR Thank you so much for your help!. I did not have access to the server logs and figured it out by trail and error. It was something that I did not expect, but your answer was still a part of the puzzle.